# Display line values instead of tooltips in NVD3 line plus bar chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

When using NVD3's line plus bar chart, instead of tooltips I need to display line labels for each xAxis point, something like below:

[image]

I need to show value as indicated by all the triangles.

Here's what my code looks :

```
rwt.chart.register("nv-line-plus-bar", function(widget) {
  var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart().margin({
    top: 10,
    right: 60,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 70
  }).x(function(d, i) {
    return i
  }).y(function(d, i) {
    return d[1]
  }).color(d3.scale.category10().range());

  chart.lines.showLabels(true);
  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart;
});
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Mike

Comment: Have you looked at the scatterChart showLabels option? It can display a label over every point. Linechart ultimately uses scatterChart. You can access the underlying scatterchart from your line chart and set labels to true.

If you provide a plunkr etc. it will be easier for people to help.

Comment: I'm trying to reach showLabels option from LinePlusBarChart, I've tried chart.lines.showLabels(true)  with no avail. I'm not foo familiar with js syntax so I'm slow on this:

rwt.chart.register("nv-line-plus-bar"
, 
 function(widget)
 {
  var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
  .margin({top: 10, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 70})
  .x(function(d,i) { return i })
  .y(function(d,i) {return d[1] })
  .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
  ;

    chart.lines.showLabels(true);
    
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    
    return chart;
    }
);